# Apache Lucene Multiple Tokenizers

Tags: java, lucene

I'm new to Lucene and have been trying to figure out a way to get an analyzer working.

I'd like my search string to be first split by a whitespace tokenizer, run through a keywordrepeatfilter, and then the non-keywords to be split by a standard analyzer.

Ex. "This-is some text" -> "this" "is" "this-is" "some" "text"

The WhitespaceAnalyzer alone wasn't working for what I wanted, so I started to try this, is there a way I can do this or should I try something different?

Comment: You can make customer Analyzers. Go look at the documentation, it's extensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can only define one Tokenizer for an Analyzer. After the Tokenizer, further modifications to the TokenStream are made using `TokenFilter`s. [`WordDelimiterFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordDelimiterFilter to achieve what you want.

This is from lucene docs

> WordDelimiterFilter Splits words into subwords and performs optional transformations on subword groups. Words are split into subwords with the following rules: - split on intra-word delimiters (by default, all non alpha-numeric characters).

The WordDelimiterFilter has **PRESERVE_ORIGINAL** property which willl split the "This-is some text" into following tokens

> this, is,this-is,text

Read more here : https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html